# Node.js getting {checkbox:id} not just id of item to delete with checkbox

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, body-parser

I have this form in an ejs template:

```
                <% items.forEach(function(item) { %>
                  <form method="POST" action="/delete">
                    <tr class="fw-normal">
                      <th class="align-middle">
                        <span><%= item.title %></span>
                      </th>
                      <td class="align-middle">
                        <span><%= item.description %></span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="align-middle">
                        <span><%= item.urgency %></span>
                      </td>
                      <td class="align-center">
                        <div class="item">
                          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%= item._id%>" onChange="this.form.submit()">
                          <span data-hidden="true" style="display: none;"><%= item.title %></span>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </form>
                <% }); %>
```

when the user clicks the checkbox I want to delete the item from my database based on its id. to check my error I'm console.logging what is being sent server side and I'm getting {checkbox: id} rather than just the id itself it seems to output key value pairs? here is my post request to the delete route:

```
app.post("/delete", function(req, res){
  const requestedItem = req.body.checkbox;
  console.log(requestedItem);
  TicketDetails.findByIdAndRemove(requestedItem).then(() => {
        console.log("Succesfully deleted checked item from the database");
        res.redirect("/main");
    }).catch((err) => {console.log(err);
    })
    res.redirect("/main");
});
```

this is my output:

[console.log of checkbox const](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsDtP.png)

req.body and req.bodycheckbox output the exact same thing but all the similar solutions suggest that the name of the checkbox should be enough to single out the value itself

Comment: [You asked this already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75986508/node-js-getting-checkbox-id-and-not-just-id-of-item-to-delete).

Comment: I kept getting that my question was too similar to others so I deleted to re word

Comment: So edit and undelete; don't duplicate.

Comment: the original post has since been deleted, I'm new to stack so I'm still working out the best ways to ask

Comment: `req.body.checkbox` should be the value. Did you restart the server after making changes?

Comment: Can you show how you setup body-parser. I guess you need to add this 
__app.use(bodyParser.json())__

Comment: I added the line above and it is now working! :) thank you, req.body.checkbox is retrieving the id